# How do I get the inspect element code instead of the page source when they are both different?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, get

I was trying to get all the links from the inspect element code of [this](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=97.0.4692.71/) website with the following code.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=97.0.4692.71/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link)
```

However, I got no links. Then, I checked what `soup` was by printing it, and I compared it to the code I got after inspecting element and viewing page source on the actual website. The code returned by `print(source)` matched that which showed up when I clicked view page source, but it did not match the code that showed up when I clicked inspect element. Firstly, how do I get the inspect element code instead of the page source code? Secondly, why are the two different?

Comment: I'm not an expert on web scraping, but a quick look shows that the page is generated by javascript, and after a few searches it looks like bs can't really get that and you would need something like selenium instead

Comment: The page works by fetching and processing XML from a [different url](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/?delimiter=/&prefix=97.0.4692.71/). You could try fetching and processing that XML directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [the other URL](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/?delimiter=/&prefix=97.0.4692.71/) mentioned in the comments and parse the `XML` with `BeautifulSoup`.

For example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/?delimiter=/&prefix=97.0.4692.71/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, features="xml").find_all("Key")
keys = [f"https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/{k.getText()}" for k in soup]
print("\n".join(keys))
```

Output:

```
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/97.0.4692.71/chromedriver_linux64.zip
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/97.0.4692.71/chromedriver_mac64.zip
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/97.0.4692.71/chromedriver_mac64_m1.zip
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/97.0.4692.71/chromedriver_win32.zip
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/97.0.4692.71/notes.txt
```